# WSO2 Developer Studio for photon Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am going to use eclipse **photon** version for WSO2 Developer Studio. Can we have way to install wso2 developer studio for eclipse photon version. Eclipse oxigen and neon working using following [link](https://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) information. I have try to install [latest version](http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/developer-studio/releases/3.8.0/) using this link. Ones install completed, Still it not showing in eclipse menu and Required ESB studio related items not there when I try to create new project.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error log of Eclipse:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.artifact.webapp [1136]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.maven.model

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1783)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1762)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1725)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1656)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)
```

a plug-in which contains org.apache.maven.model is missing.

Having a look into there Eclipse Marketplace entry (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wso2-developer-studio) it seems that they offer no version for the latest Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 developer studio current version is based on Eclipse Oxygen and it hasn't been migrated to photon yet https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2479 .